# UINavigationController - implementing back to beginning button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a UINavigationController which has several screens that implement a logical set of stepped tasks ...

Is there a way that on the last screen I can have logic on a done button that would take me to the start without having to step back through the screens ?

I am really looking for code examples of the logic I would need to put on the done button?

Many thanks

Comment: You can re-initialize the navigation Controller & push the start view on Done Button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pop directly to rootview controller instead of just popping.

use:

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: @rs2000: but remember next time before creating new question,do some research because its simple one.

Answer (score 1):

use this

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

[popToRootViewControllerAnimated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToRootViewControllerAnimated%3a) -> **It will pops all the view controllers on the stack except the root view controller and updates the display.**

```
[yourNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you want to use [popToViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController%3aanimated%3a) then

```
id rootView=[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:rootView animated:YES];
```

Comment: why are you post same answer agian..

Comment: Not the same yaar...I was busy with searching in class reference for exact definition. thats why i am late..

Comment: @NitinGohel - universal coding will never change yar..

Comment: This answer is not only for the owner of question, it will for all the  user who are looking for navigationController ..

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to achieve this thing on DONE button ;

**1)** If your rootview is the view from where you want to restart than you can use as follows -

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**2)** Else you can `re-initialize the navigation Controller & push` to the start view.

Hope this will help.